# How to implement point source or volume source in finite element implementations

Tags: finite-element, numerics, numerical-modelling, advection-diffusion, microfluidics

I'm trying to do a simple implementation to study the advection-diffusion-reaction dynamics in a straight pipe.
[image]

I have points positioned along the length of the pipe (blue dots in the image above).

I came across a blog ([link](https://www.comsol.com/blogs/how-to-implement-a-point-source-with-the-weak-form/)) that explains how a point source is implemented. However, I am not really sure how to adapt it in this case.

The equation that captures the concentration dynamics is the following

[image]

The R in the last term of RHS corresponds to sink/source and the units is generally defined in mol/m^3 s. I want to define R = kc where the units of k is per sec. But I want to define R only at the points colored blue (i.e only as a point source/sink and not as a line source or sink).

I would like to ask for suggestions on how this implementation can be done.

EDIT:
I would like to compare the FEM result obtained for 1D straight pipe simulation of convection-diffusion dynamics with point sinks located along the length of the pipe (problem posted above) against the analytical solution.

Suggestions on the analytical expression against which the numerical result can be compared will be really helpful.

Comment: If you want to add them as point sources in your nodes I think that you can add them to the right have side vector.

Comment: @nicoguaro From what I understand, by default software like COMSOL allows the implementation of a line source since the source/sink term R is associated with area. Could you please elaborate? I'm a bit confused about how to add a point source/sink here.

Comment: Does the documentation of deal.II's `VectorTools::create_point_source_rhs()` function help? https://dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/namespaceVectorTools.html#ac4e531baa71a5183079fd2083aa7d723

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you, this really helps in understanding how vector implementation can be done to define the delta function at each point. But I am still having trouble in understanding what must the units of the function that defines point source/sink. Could you please explain this a bit ?

Comment: What do you mean by "units"?

Comment: You could have something like $R = \delta(x - x_i)$ to represent a point source.

Comment: @nicoguaro Please correct me if I am wrong. This would be R=δ(x−xi) a constant value at all points along the length of the pipe and also constant over time ?.

Comment: If the bounty is trying to get this for Comsol, I would say that that question is off-topic here. But, if you need a point load/boundary condition you could use a small segment/surface and apply it there.

Comment: @nicoguaro No, this bounty isn't for Comsol. Please check my edit

Comment: I think that should be another question.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thanks, I have posted this question in a new thread as well [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/37637/does-the-time-dependent-1d-advection-diffusion-with-point-sources-have-an-analyt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen that you also have an account over at [mathematica stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions) I am going to show an implementation using Mathematica. This is certainly not the only way you can do it but hopefully gets you started.

We start by creating a 1D mesh

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
region = Line[{{0}, {1}}];
includePoints = {{1/3}, {2/3}};
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "IncludePoints" -> includePoints, 
  "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0008]
```

The mesh has points included at 1/3 and 2/3. This is where we will position the point sources later. I also refined the mesh, because I am going to add a convection term which will make this PDE convection dominant (large Peclet number).

We set up the dependent variable, the mass concentration $c$, time variable $t$ and the spatial independent variable $x$. Also some material properties are defined.

```
vars = {c[t, x], t, {x}};
pars = <|"DiffusionCoefficient" -> 1, 
   "MassConvectionVelocity" -> {100}|>;
```

For the point sources the idea is to use a regularized delta function. The Dirac delta function poses a problem in numerical simulations with FEM implementation that is not prepared to take it as an input. This is because the Dirac delta function is singular at the source location $X_s$ and needs special treatment that differs  from how FEM treats other terms. This can be avoided with an approximation to the Dirac delta function. The process of approximating the Dirac delta function is called regularization.

```
RegularizedDeltaPoint[g_, X_List, Xs_List] := 
 Piecewise[{{Times @@ Thread[1/(4 g) (1 + Cos[\[Pi]/(2 g) (X - Xs)])],
     And @@ Thread[RealAbs[X - Xs] <= 2 g]}, {0, True}}]
```

More information about this can be found in the [Heat Transfer tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#945943234). The process for mass transport is the same. So if you also want to volume sources you can proceed in the same way as mentioned in that tutorial.

```
Subscript[h, mesh] = Sqrt[Min[mesh["MeshElementMeasure"]]];
Subscript[gamma, reg] = Subscript[h, mesh]/2;
```

The regularization function needs a parameter gamma, which is based on the minimal element diameter. Let's construct the point source at the first included point and visualize it.

```
temp = RegularizedDeltaPoint[Subscript[gamma, reg], {x}, 
  includePoints[[1]]];
Plot[temp, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

You see that this is an idealized approximation to the delta distribution. Note that

```
Integrate[temp, {x, 0, 1}]
1.
```

The Comsol approach uses a weak formulation. That is a different approach. I am trying to show that (point) sources can be set up in different ways.

```
Qp = 10;
pars["MassSource"] = 
  RegularizedDeltaPoint[Subscript[gamma, reg], {x}, 
     includePoints[[1]]]*Qp +
   RegularizedDeltaPoint[Subscript[gamma, reg], {x}, 
     includePoints[[2]]]*If[t > 1/2*10^-3, 5*Qp, 0];
```

`Qp` is the point source strength. The unit would be [$mol/(m^3 s)$], because the regularization function is dimension less the source has the same units as the overall PDE components, see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#1962299513). The first point source is active all the time while the second only starts at a specific time but is stronger.

We set up the PDE and solve it.

```
pde = {MassTransportPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 0, c[0, x] == 0};
tEnd = 10^-3;
cfun = NDSolveValue[pde, c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x} \[Element] mesh];
```

Visualize / explore the result.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[cfun[t, x], {x} \[Element] region, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1/2}}], {t, 0, tEnd}]
```

[image]

More information can be found in the [Mass Transport tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/MassTransport/MassTransport.html) and the [MassTransportPDEComponent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#888398773).

I hope this is useful to you.

***Update for older version:***

The code I posted above works for version 12.3. Since the OP has 12.0 the following is the same code, suitable for version 12.0. In essence the `MassTransportPDEComponent` is not available in 12.0. But that's not a problem as one can write the PDE manually. Here is the complete code:

This first part is the same as before:

```
RegularizedDeltaPoint[g_, X_List, Xs_List] := 
  Piecewise[{{Times @@ 
      Thread[1/(4 g) (1 + Cos[\[Pi]/(2 g) (X - Xs)])], 
     And @@ Thread[RealAbs[X - Xs] <= 2 g]}, {0, True}}];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
region = Line[{{0}, {1}}];
includePoints = {{1/3}, {2/3}};
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "IncludePoints" -> includePoints, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0008];

Subscript[h, mesh] = Sqrt[Min[mesh["MeshElementMeasure"]]];
Subscript[gamma, reg] = Subscript[h, mesh]/2;
```

This part is where things change. I added a parameters section and added a manual form of the PDE.

```
parameters = {kappa -> {{1}}, v1 -> 100, 
   gamma -> Subscript[gamma, reg], Qp -> 10};
pde = {Derivative[1, 0][c][t, x] + 
      Inactive[Div][(-kappa) . 
        Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}], {x}] + {v1} . 
       Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}] - 
      Qp*RegularizedDeltaPoint[gamma, {x}, {1/3}] - 
      If[t > 1/2000, 5*Qp, 0]*
       RegularizedDeltaPoint[gamma, {x}, {2/3}] == 0, 
    c[0, x] == 0} /. parameters;

tEnd = 10^-3;
cfun = NDSolveValue[pde, c, {t, 0, tEnd}, {x} \[Element] mesh];
```

This should give you the same result in version 12.0.

***Update: Cloud version***

Another alternative is to use the wolfram cloud. Here is a [cloud version of the notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ruebenko/Published/CS_PointSource.nb).

Comment: Hi, I've copied the lines of code posted by you to try this out.  Please find the notebook [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/point_sink.nb). I get the following error :`NDSolveValue::derivs: No derivatives of dependent variables were found in the equations. NDSolveValue is designed to solve differential or differential algebraic equations. Use NSolve or FindRoot to numerically solve algebraic equations.`. Could you please help me in resolving this?

Comment: @Natasha, what version do you have?

Comment: I'm using version 12.

Comment: @Natasha, see update.

Comment: Thank you, this works!. Could you please let me know how the boundary condition is specified? I want to define Dirichlet at the left boundary and Neumann at the right boundary.

Comment: I want to define point source at 4 points in my domain. `region = Line[{{0}, {100}}];
includePoints = {{10}, {20}, {30}, {40}};` . And I want to define all point sources active at all time. I am not sure how  `pde = {Derivative[1, 0][c][t, x] + 
      Inactive[Div][(-kappa) . 
        Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}], {x}] + {v1} . 
       Inactive[Grad][c[t, x], {x}] - 
      Qp*RegularizedDeltaPoint[gamma, {x}, {1/3}] - 
      If[t > 1/2000, 5*Qp, 0]*
       RegularizedDeltaPoint[gamma, {x}, {2/3}] == 0, 
    c[0, x] == 0} /. parameters;` has to be modified.

Comment: I would also like to know how to plot the solution curves at the point sink positions. Example, I want to see how the concentration profile evolved and saturates at  `includePoints = {{10}, {20}, {30}, {40}}` these points. Please fine my notebook [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/point_sink.nb). Thanks a lot.

Comment: I modified  the original code posted here to incorporate the points mentioned in the above comments. For some reason, the code takes a long time to run so I had to abort it after 10 minutes. In addition to modification in the domain, I have also changed the values of the diffusion coefficient and velocity, tEnd. I couldn't understand what kappa is and wha are the boundary conditions  in the pde function that is defined, please explain. Could you please have a look at the notebook with modification shared [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/point_sink.nb)?

Comment: I have seen you already got an answer to your follow up questions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249905/18437).

Comment: Yes, could you please clarify a small doubt? From the other post I learnt that by default 0 Neumann is defined at the right boundary. Is this is same default setting for the left boundary as well?

Comment: @Natasha, any part of the boundary that is not specified defaults to a Neumann 0 boundary condition.

Comment: :) Thanks a lot for the clarification. I am really sorry for another question here. Could you please help me with this: `May I also know how to save the solution in cfun at includePoints = {{10}, {20}, {30}, {40}, {50}} over the integration time span to a text file?` ? I did post this question in my other post too but I didn't get an answer for this part of my question.

Comment: Depends a bit on how you want things to be formatted, you could start with this: `data = Table[
   Flatten[cfun[t, #] & /@ includePoints], {t, 0, tEnd, tEnd/10}];
Export["~/data.txt", data, "CSV"]`

Comment: `Qp is the point source strength. The unit would be [mol/s]` . Is this units in [mol/l/s] instead?

Comment: @Natasha, that's correct. I fixed it in the text.

Comment: I would like to know there is an analytical solution for this problem. I'd like to compare this numerical solution with analytical solution.  Actually, I tried a finite-difference implementation for this problem. i.e. using method of lines approach the first and second spatial derivatives were discretized and source terms were added at `include_points` .The resulting ode was solved using ode15s in MATLAB. I found the steady-state observed at the positions in `include_points` are quite different from the values obtained via FEM in MMA.

Comment: Natasha, you keep asking new questions. Perhaps you should not ask me these questions but post a new question on a relevant site. - I am not aware of an analytical solution, but that does not mean that none exists.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand I should have opened this as a new thread. But I made an edit here with bounty points for the new question. Probably I will award to your answer and start a new bounty again if I don't get an answer in my other post. Sorry for constantly posting here, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what [@user21's answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/37536/9667), I don't think that you need to do anything special for point loads. Let's see why.

A point load can be represented as a [Dirac delta "function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). So, in your case it would be something like

$$R = \rho \delta(x - x_i)\, ,$$

where $\rho$ is the intensity of the source and $x_i$ is the position.

If we use a weighted residuals for the finite element method you end up with the following integral for "body" sources

$$b = \int_\Omega R(x) w(x)\, ,$$

being $w(x)$ the weight function. If $R(x) = \rho \delta(x - x_i)$,

$$b = \int_\Omega \rho \delta(x - x_i) w(x) = \rho w(x_i)\, .$$

Thus, it suffices to evaluate your weight function in the point $x_i$. For "common" finite elements, we use interpolating functions. This implies the following

$$b = \begin{cases}
\rho\quad \text{for nodes}\, ,\\
\rho \phi_j(r_i)\quad \text{otherwise}\, ,
\end{cases}$$

where $r_i$ represents the position of the point in the reference element.

Notice the following:

- For points that coincide with nodes (your case) the source contribute to exactly one entry in the $b$ vector. But for points inside elements it contributes to all the nodes related to that element, one for each function $\phi_j$.
- For linear elements $\phi_j(r_i) > 0$, but that's not the case for higher-order elements.

Regarding the question if one should or should not use point sources and its physical interpretation... It is a different matter, more related to the physics of the problem, I would argue. Respecting the units that you mention at the end of your question, I think that you don't provide enough information to assess it.

Comment: As I said, there are many ways to do it.

Comment: @user21, yes. But you also said this: "The Dirac delta function poses a problem in numerical simulations as it can not be resolved in the discretized spatial domain. This is because the Dirac delta function is singular at the source location Xs. Hence, an approximation to the Dirac delta function is needed"

Comment: I see what you are saying, but that has the disadvantage that for a general purpose FEM code you'd need to introduce some spacial case code, no? - my approach works for other FEM codes that do not have this specifically build in. I have reworded my answer a bit to reflect that.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I tried setting up the system described in my original post i.e. add point source at the blue points. As shown in the example demonstrated [here](https://www.comsol.com/blogs/how-to-implement-a-point-source-with-the-weak-form/) I defined Q*test(u) in the weak form PDE. But the solution failed to converge. I am not sure if this is due to the singularity of the delta function at the source point.

Comment: I would be happy to share my COMSOL file if someone can please have a look

Comment: @Natasha, I suggest that you try to solve a simpler problem with a point load. For example, you could try to solve Poisson equation. Regarding the details on how to use that on Comsol, I think that you could get better luck in one of their channels.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thank you. Unfortunately, the answers given for my query in comol support channel didn't help me in solving the convergence issue that I am facing.

Comment: @Natasha, did you figure this out?

Comment: @user21 Hi, I've been asked to do this implementation in comsol and unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to do this in comsol.

Comment: @Natasha, I could imagine that this does not work in comsol, as when you specify the expression with the test function `Q*test(u)` comsol will still integrate over it, and, if I understand nicoguaro's answer correctly, you do not want this. Again, I do not have access to comsol and this is a shot in the blue. You could try to impose this as a `DirichletCondition` where you use comsol's `h(x) u = r(x)` and have `h(x)=1` and `r(x)=if(x==POS), Q, 0)`. maybe that works. Or, as an alternative, my approach will work. Specify the regularization function and then call it in the load vector.